VS2019 MASM64 x64 windows assembly CreateFileMapping
I would like to ask how to use the CreateFileMapping function in x64 assembly.i use vs2019 masm64, I'm having trouble with it.LINK  error lnk2019 unresolved external symbol CreateFileMapping.
My code looks like this:
extrn ExitProcess:proc
extrn CreateFileA:proc
extrn GetFileSize:proc
extrn CreateFileMapping:proc
includelib   user32.lib
includelib kernel32.lib
includelib ucrt.lib
includelib legacy_stdio_definitions.lib
.data
filename  db "test1.txt",0;
size__ db 4 dup(?)
filehandle_ db 8 dup(?)
hmap db 8 dup(?)
pmapview db 4 dup(?)
.code
main proc

    nop
   
   lea rcx,filename
   mov rdx,0c0000000h
   mov r8,0
   mov r9,0
   push 0
   push 0  
   push 3  ;OPEN_EXISTING 3
   sub rsp,20h
   call CreateFileA
   add rsp,20h
   add rsp,24
   ;CreateFileA
   cmp rax,-1
   je endl
   mov qword ptr [filehandle_],rax  


   mov rcx,qword ptr[filehandle_]
   mov rdx,0
   sub rsp,28h
   call GetFileSize
   add rsp,28h
  ; GetFileSize
   cmp eax,-1;0xFFFFFFFF
   je endl
   mov dword ptr[size__],eax 


  mov rcx,qword ptr[filehandle_]
  mov rdx,0
  mov r8,4;PAGE_READWRITE
  mov r9,0
  push 0
  push 0
  sub rsp,20h
 call CreateFileMapping
  add rsp,20h
  add rsp,16
  test rax,rax
  jz endl
  mov qword ptr[hmap],rax

    endl:
    sub rsp,28h
    call ExitProcess
    add rsp,28h
main ENDP

END ;
error lnk2019 unresolved external symbol CreateFileMapping

Do you understand why you had to use CreateFileA instead of just CreateFile?  It's the same problem for CreateFileMapping.

thank you,i use CreateFileMappingA,then compile suc
